# configuration exception on hibernate mappingexception unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I am a beginner in hibernate. I am following this hello world tutorial from http://javapostsforlearning.blogspot.in/2013/01/hibernate-hello-world-example-in-eclipse.html
but I am facing the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2018)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1935)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1914)
    at org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: adding hbm.xml into your `applicationContext.xml` or just use annotation and resource scanner

Comment: Post your hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: i see in this post many users facing issue in this post with their configuration file. post it plese.

Comment: The program you are running is using Microsoft SqlServer database. You should change the **driver class, connection parameter and dialect** according to the database in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.